# Excel Interop does not register programmatically my workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I am making, in my forms application, an excel file that contains data.

I am doing it with Excel Interop.

The thing is, when I say to register, it does not, and it open the windows dialog (like if in Excel, I clicked on save as..), while I told him to register, into a specific path.

The Excel file does not exist, It is a creation.

And when I do not register, and just tell it to show the excel file, no problems.

The code (just the end) :

```
    there is no problem with that code
                app.Visible = true;


//but there is a problem with this one
                    //app.Visible = true;



                    object save = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAction.xlSaveChanges;
                    object excelFileName = tbCible.Text + "\\export.xlsx";
                    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)workbook).Close(save, excelFileName, oMissing);
//closing the excel file and process
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
                    worksheet = null;
                    workbook = null;
                    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application)app).Quit();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);

                    app = null;
```

Why does he ask where I want to save my file, while I told him to register into a specific path, and with a filename earlier?

And how can I save my Excel file programatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by calling `Workbook.SaveAs` to save the file, then calling `Workbook.Close` with SaveChanges = false.

Comment: Indeed this works better , thank you .Is there any explanation, that I can't do it, with my original code?

Comment: @Zaphod, not sure why it didn't work, but SaveAs gives you more options / control, and would be my preferred solution.  It should work in exactly the same way as equivalent code in VBA, so if I wanted to understand what's going on, I't start by trying to create a repro in VBA.  I think that if you ask a VBA question, you'd be more likely to get a response from someone with an in-depth understanding of the Excel object model.